# Sending input to fields doesnt always work

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I am trying to scrape this page:
https://shop.mango.com/us/plus-size/shirts-blouses/satin-wrap-blouse_67020035.html?c=28&n=1&s=prendas_violeta.familia;414

Go to  "discover my size" and then enter values of height and weight there. The problem is that it doesn't work alot of times which makes scraping quite slow. This is my code

## click whats my size button

```
    size = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[4]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/main/div/div[3]/div[3]/form/div[1]/button"))).click()



    # get the window handle after a new window has opened

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver,20)

    #driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("/html/body/div[9]"))
    time.sleep(2)

    height = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[9]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/input[1]")))

    height.send_keys(str(df_temp['heightfeet']))
```

I have changed last statement to this too:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', '" +str(df_temp['heightfeet']) + "')", height);
```

It just doesnt work often. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score -1):

Use following code,

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import time

driver=webdriver.Chrome('D:/chromedriver.exe')

url = 'https://shop.mango.com/us/plus-size/shirts-blouses/satin-wrap-blouse_67020035.html?c=28&n=1&s=prendas_violeta.familia;414'
driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#seleccionPais > div > div > div.modalPopUp__body > div.modalConfirmacionPaisForm__buttonContainer.modalForm.lang1 > div.modalEnterForm__lang.modalEnterFormLang > a').click()
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#productForm > form > div.size-finder-container > button').click()
time.sleep(2)
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="uclw_form_height"]''')
inputElement.clear()
inputElement.send_keys('140')                               
time.sleep(2)                                
inputElement = driver.find_element_by_xpath('''//*[@id="uclw_form_weight"]''')
time.sleep(2)  
inputElement.clear()
inputElement.send_keys('65')      
time.sleep(2)  
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#uclw_save_info_button').click()
```

Comment: gives exception. Element not interactable

Comment: Try setting more sleep time.